# Exporting an object to a ZIP file

Tags: java, file, io, serialization, compression

I have my own type of object, which implements Serializable. Here I have one called "`extendedFormat`" (not a terribly helpful name, yes, I know). I'm writing it out to a file like so:

```
try {
    // is this the best way to do this????????
    // this seems like too many streams perhaps.
    // like maybe this is now a river
    File file = new File("C:/temp/tempExport.bef");
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream);
    ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(bufferStream);
    zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("bef"));
    ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(zipStream);
    objectStream.writeObject(extendedFormat);
    zipStream.closeEntry();
    objectStream.close();
    zipStream.close();
    bufferStream.close();
    fileStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is this the best way to do this? It seems a little over complicated but I want to save as much time writing it out and also space in terms of how big the file is that I write out.

I know this may seem like a lot for one object, but it can hold an entire table with possibly hundreds of columns and thousands of rows, so efficiency is important.

Comment: Do you have any hard requirements to use Java < 8, or would you consider using a library for this?

Comment: @PanayiotisPoularakis no, a library would be fine as long as it is one I can use in a commercial application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)  to efficiently close the streams, this also reduces line count and readability.

IOUtils provides a tested utility to copy between input and output streams, add commons-compress to you classpath, for example using gradle

```
 compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress',version: '1.14'
```

I simply extended the code you provided. I believe you will get the idea for reading back the zip file.

```
  try {

            File file = new File("C:/temp/tempExport.bef");
            file.createNewFile();

//Use try with resources to handle closing streams

            try (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)))) {
                zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("bef"));
                ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(zipStream);
                objectStream.writeObject(extendedFormat);
            }

         //to read the file you need a temp buffer or file to decompress the archive
            File temp = Files.createTempFile("", "").toFile();

            try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(temp));
                 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(temp))) {
                zis.getNextEntry();
                IOUtils.copy(zis, bos);
                bos.close();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
                ExtendedFormat extendedFormat= (ExtendedFormat) ois.readObject();
            }

            temp.delete();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```